# How to submit form on webpage in PYTHON?

Tags: python

I want to tick checkboxes, select radio buttons, write in text boxes and finally click on submit button to submit the form on a page. Programming in PYTHON only. How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

There are quite some solution. You can explore them and come back with a program, if it does not work.

- Mechanize: http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

  - [Python Auto Fill with Mechanize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516655/python-auto-fill-with-mechanize)
- Twill : - http://twill.idyll.org/
- Python Paste: http://pythonpaste.org/
- PAMIE: http://pamie.sourceforge.net/