# How do I submit a request for a new Google account?

Tags: javascript, python, html, urllib

I want to make a command line account maker (in python). It shows you the ReCapatcha using `PIL.Image.Image.show()` and submits the request to google after you enter all the information.

I've never been very good at JavaScript or HTML, so I couldn't make right or left of the code on the [accounts.google.com/SignUp](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp) page.

What is the url I would submit the request to, and what request would it be? Thanks.

Comment: Google most likely prevents requests from being submitted from a different computer than the ReCaptcha was answered on (as I understand it, ReCaptcha sends a response back to the website using it).

Comment: It's the same computer. I never said it was coming from a different server.

Comment: I guess you could use scrappy or something to get the captcha img url and display it prompting the user to enter the details

Comment: That's the whole point of the recaptcha! To avoid automated account creation (via scripts/bots/etc.).

Comment: Save yourself a lot of grief and simply open a URL and point to accounts.google.com/SignUp from your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Code Monkey said, it's impossible to achieve this using your current method. However, there may be another way. Instead of getting the user to fill in the data before querying the site, make your program behave like a normal web browser.

You could use the [urllib.request](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2.3/library/urllib.request.html) module to open the account creation page and download the raw html.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen("https://accounts.google.com/NewAccount").read().decode('utf-8')
```

From there, pick out the URL of the ReCAPTCHA image with regex.

```
import re
token = re.search("accounts.google.com/Captcha\?ctoken=([^\"]+)", html).group(1)
url = "https://accounts.google.com/Captcha?ctoken=" + token
```

You can then download the image from the URL and display it the user.

As for actually submitting the form, I suspect that you will need to set the `data` parameter of `urlopen` with the data the user provides and make a POST request to another URL, but I haven't verified this.

An addon for Firefox that I've found to be extremely helpful for this kind of stuff is [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/). It allows you to see exactly what your browser is doing, including showing what the POST/GET requests look like, the URL's you're accessing, and other useful information.

Alternatively:

- Use the [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) library ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3516692/369977))
- Just open up a web browser window to the signup page and get your user to create an account the way Google intended.

I should also add that I don't condone violating [Google's TOS](http://www.google.ca/intl/en/policies/terms/regional.html) with mass account creation (for the purposes of spamming or otherwise). Google provides a great service. Please don't abuse it.

Answer (score 5):

The simple answer - you don't.  There is no way around the bot-catcher.  This is not the popular answer, but it is the only true one.  Data for the ReCapatcha is stored on the server, not sent to the client (obviously; this is the whole point).  I hate being that guy, but you don't need the url or the message because your task is impossible.  Sorry.

Comment: Google goes to **huge** effort to prevent programmatic creation of accounts.  If you solve the captcha, something else will bite you.  Even if you _do_ manage to make it work, spammers will find out, start using it, and then Google will find a way to make it _not_ work.  Don't waste your time.